# How do I determine if my javascript uses too many resources (and help optimizing)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is this horribly inefficient or does it look ok???  How do I test resources used by it?

```
$.easing.def = "easeOutBack";
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var numResults = $("#scroll > div").size();
            var scrollSize = numResults * 264;
            var stopSize = ((numResults - 6) * 264) * -1;
            $("#scroll").width(scrollSize);
            $("#page-left").hide();
            $("#page-right").click(function() {
                var marginleft = parseInt(jQuery("#scroll").css("margin-left"));
                if(marginleft > stopSize) {
                    $("#page-left").show();
                    $(this).hide();
                    $("#scroll").animate({"margin-left": "-=783px"}, 800, function() {
                        var marginleft = parseInt(jQuery("#scroll").css("margin-left"));
                        if(marginleft > stopSize) {
                            $("#page-right").show();
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
            $("#page-left").click(function() {
                var marginright = parseInt(jQuery("#scroll").css("margin-left"));
                if(marginright < -10) {
                    $("#page-right").show();
                    $(this).hide();
                    $("#scroll").animate({"margin-left": "+=783px"}, 800, function() {
                        var marginright = parseInt(jQuery("#scroll").css("margin-left"));
                        if(marginright < -10) {
                            $("#page-left").show();
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: Try [jQuery lint](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/jquery-lint/). It can be installed as a firefox add-on.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome gives you the ability to take heap snapshots. DeveloperTools->Profiles->HeapSnapshots

You can take snapshot at various time intervals to compare memory usage. 
Another option is paid one http://www.softwareverify.com/javascript/memory/feature.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any reason why that would consume much in terms of resources. You're just animating things left and right, right? I guess some better coding practices that I'd point out would be to store things you use repeatedly like `$("#scroll")` in a variable so you don't search the DOM every time for the same thing, and also choosing one of `jQuery` or `$` unless you need to do otherwise.

The real question I'd have is what exactly `783` represents. If it's because your screen is 800 pixels wide, then keep in mind that not everyone will see you page that way.

As for the profiling part, Rizwan's answer gets +1.

Comment: "store things you use repeatedly like $("#scroll") in a variable so you don't search the DOM every time for the same thing"
Always wondered about that myself. Personally, I think that is something that the JS runtime would be optimizing by keeping a copy of recent look-ups but I always do that myself.